# JBOSS Fuse Starter questions

Tags: jbossfuse

So, I'm looking at using Fuse to replace an existing integration engine, and suite of integrations at work.
I've started looking at using Fuse, and it looks as good as, or better than the competition.
I have installed the Fuse Development Environment, watched a few videos, and worked through the first couple homeloan tutorials.

I'm having a couple of problems:
1) When I try to do a JSON to XML transformation, I drag out the data transformation icon from the palette, specify from JSON (with a piece of sample JSON), specify to XML (with a sample SOAP request) and click OK.  I always get the same error message:
[image: not the most useful error message]

Any suggestions about what I'm doing wrong?  This seems to work, if I have a template (XSD) file of the request instead of XML, but that's not normally an option.

2) Where is the HTTP Client component?  I see long lists of components on web pages, and I see a whole bunch in the palette in Fuse, but I can't see a simple HTTP Client (or server) component!! What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1) I fear that you hit this known bug: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/FUSETOOLS-1720
Can you vote on the issue? If it is possible, can you provide the files that you are using on the issue please? It will help to reproduce and ensure your usecase will be fixed.

2) In the upcoming release, you will have access to a lot more of Components by using the Generic palette item, see https://issues.jboss.org/browse/FUSETOOLS-1709
With current version, you can modify the uri parameter after adding an element.

Comment: woah, thanks!   That helps a lot.

1) possibly, this was JSON to XML, not xml to xml.
Earlier I had the same issue with XML to XML.  The error went away when I switched to xsd to define the outbound.